# Issue Downloading PDF with urllib on Website Requiring Authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf-generation, urllib, mechanicalsoup

I'm trying to get pdf files behind a domain that requires a username and password. I am able to get MechanicalSoup to enter my login credentials, however when I navigate to the pdf file I can view the pdf fine with MechanicalSoups launch_browser() but I cannot download the pdf. In the past (when using BeautifulSoup in python 2 for a site that didn't require authentication) I would just pass the url to urllib2 like so:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)
file = open(fileName, 'w')
file.write(page.read())
file.close()
```

When I do similarly to urllib.requests I found that I now have to enter my login credentials again. So I tried (following directions [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml)):

```
loginUrl = "http://..."
urlToPDF = "http://..."
passman = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, loginUrl, "username", "password")

authhandler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(authhandler)

urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlToPDF)
file = open("test.pdf", "wb")
file.write(page.read())
file.close()
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. When I change the filename to "test" (removed the ".pdf") and open in chrome it appears that it wrote to the file the webpage that says I need to click the button which would redirect me to the login page. Hence why I tried using both loginUrl and urlToPDF in the above code.

The forums I've read so far seem to say the above should work. Alternatively, considering I can view the pdf using MechanicalSoup is there a way to download a pdf directly with MechanicalSoup?

Comment: I don't know about your particular case, but many website examine the referrer field to check that you're actually coming from the download page, and show you that HTML page otherwise. If it's the case, then MechanicalSoup should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly download the PDF using MechanicalSoup.

The return value of many of the [StatefulBrowser](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mechanicalsoup.html#mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser) methods (including `StatefulBrowser.open` and `StatefulBrowser.follow_link`) is a [requests.Response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) object. If the request is successful, then the data you want is stored in the `Response.content` attribute. So, to download the file amounts to writing this attribute to a file!

Here is an example:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
response = browser.open("http://example.com/example.pdf")

with open('your_filename_here.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

In the future, I expect that MechanicalSoup will implement this more directly as a `StatefulBrowser.download` method (or something along those lines). See [this issue](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup/issues/170) on the MechanicalSoup GitHub page to follow the development of this feature.

Comment: It worked, thank you :) the one issue I now have is that apparently reading the file written file the response.content is stored as a <!DOCTYPE html> so I need to convert the html to pdf